# emulated of full join return wrong values

Tags: mysql, join, union

I have two tables that doesn't have relationship and I do a left and right join to simulate a full join on them and select some data.
the manner of displaying data is right but values are wrong, its looks like they selected more than once.
my tables are something like this :
TABLE 1 (bargains)
trade_date ----  profit

TABLE 2 (general_cost)
date ----- cost

this is the query that i write :

```
select b.trade_date, coalesce(sum(b.profit),0),  coalesce(sum(g.cost),0)  
from bargains as b 
left join general_cost as g on b.trade_date =  g.date group by b.trade_date 
union
select g.date, coalesce(sum(b.profit),0), coalesce(sum(g.cost),0) from
bargains as b
right join general_cost as g on b.trade_date =  g.date  group by g.date
```

this is the result of query :

[image]

for example in date 1395-9-28 the sum of profit column should be 440 and sum of cost column should be 800
if it's help you should know that there is three row with this date in bargains table and two row in general_cost table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your query duplicates the matching records because those are included in both left and the right join. You need to exclude the matching records from one of the queries. I usually exclude them from the 2nd query of the union:

```
select b.trade_date, coalesce(sum(b.profit),0),  coalesce(sum(g.cost),0)  
from bargains as b 
left join general_cost as g on b.trade_date =  g.date group by b.trade_date 
union
select g.date, coalesce(sum(b.profit),0), coalesce(sum(g.cost),0) from
bargains as b
right join general_cost as g on b.trade_date =  g.date
where b.date is null //include only the records from general_cost that are not matched 
group by g.date
```

UPDATE

If you have multiple records in both tables with the same date, then you need to do the summing per table separately in subqueries, otherwise the matching records do get duplicated:

```
select b.trade_date, b.profit,  coalesce(g.cost,0)  
from (select trade_date, sum(profit) as profit from bargains group by trade_date) as b 
left join (select date, sum(cost) as cost from general_cost group by date) as g on b.trade_date =  g.date
union
select g.date, 0, sum(g.cost) from //all profits has been summed up in the above query, so here we can use 0 in place of profit
bargains as b
right join general_cost as g on b.trade_date =  g.date
where b.trade_date is null //include only the records from general_cost that are not matched 
group by g.date
```

Comment: i use the where clause but number of returned rows by query is 9 i mean its get less but still i receive the same result for that date it means still there is a match at both table. do u think the problem is because i use group by?

Comment: Ah, had the `where` at the wrong place, needs to come ahead of the group by. Answer updated.

Comment: i know i do it right i change the where clause but still the result is what i said. can i send you the result of query when i remove the sum from query, because as you said it should exclude the null value but there isn't a null value for example there is three copy of same value in cost column for each date in profit column what should i do now

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: thank you so much it is work correctly as I want, just I want to know is it possible to group the result by month()  and year() commands, so we would have our costs and profit monthly not daily.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131792/discussion-between-alidk-and-shadow).